# How to use multiple conditional expressions to select values from a NUMPY array？

Tags: python, numpy

```
b = np.array([2,3,4,5])
b[b>=1]
```

we can get the values which are greater than 1 in b.

However

```
b = np.array([2,3,4,5])
b[b>=1 and b <= 2]
```

will raise ValueError.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: `b[(b >= 1) & (b <= 2)]`

Comment: @MechanicPig In this particular instance could you also do `b[1 <= b <= 2]`?

Comment: @flakes No, `1 <= b <= 2` is equivalent to `1 <= b and b <= 2` instead of `(1 <= b) & (b <= 2)`. The root of the problem is that python does not allow overloading of `and`, `or` and `not`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = np.array([2,3,4,5])
b[(b>=1) & ( b <= 2)]
```